# Windows 8 app live tile has "X" in the bottom right corner

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Just today I started noticing an "X" symbol in the bottom right of my live tiles, see picture.

I'm a little concerned, as I'm currently in the certification queue, that this means I've missed something from the package - a default badge image, for example.  Do you know what this means?

[image: Live Tile for Word Search Party]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears to be that your developer licence has expired!

when I tried to build something I got a popup alerting me to the problem and asking me to log in to my account again.  At which point I was given a new developer licence, was able to build again, and all the crosses magically disappeared! :o)

I imagine the only reason your apps were still working was because they were still in a suspended state so weren't going through a proper launch cycle.  The X means it won't run anymore as you don't have a valid licence.